# Coffeescript compiles but does not seem to work

Tags: coffeescript

```
jQuery ($) ->
    eventMethod = if window.addEventListener then "addEventListener" else "attachEvent"
    eventer = window[eventMethod]
    messageEvent = eventMethod == if "attachEvent" then "onmessage" else "message"

    # Listen to message from child window
    eventer messageEvent, (e) ->
        console.log "parent received message!:  #{e.data}"
        newHeight = e.data
        $("#cf-iframe").css("height", newHeight)
    , false
```

As a follow up to another post. My above coffeescript compiles nicely. Yet it doesn't behave as it should. It doesn't seem to have attached the event listener to the window correctly. Can anyone help me with working out why?

Comment: On point is that `messageEvent` is a local variable in the `jQuery ($) -> ` function scope and thus not defined when you invoke the "eventer" function. The same applies to "eventer" itself.

Comment: Think that was just my bad indenting on here. It is all wrapped with the jQuery function scope. Would adding the compiled outcome help as well?

Comment: Okay, I see, so that's not the problem. But what also appears strange to me is the fourth line, shouldn't that be something like: `messageEvent = if eventMethod is "attachEvent" then "onmessage" else "message"` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Niko's right, this doesn't make much sense:

```
messageEvent = eventMethod == if "attachEvent" then "onmessage" else "message"
```

The inlined `if` has higher precedence than `==` which has higher precedence than `=` so you're actually saying:

```
messageEvent = (eventMethod == (if "attachEvent" then "onmessage" else "message"))
```

The string `"attachEvent"` is truthy so you're actually saying:

```
messageEvent = (eventMethod == "onmessage")
```

or shorter still:

```
messageEvent = false
```

The `eventer` function doesn't know what to do with a boolean so the whole thing ends up doing nothing.

I think you want to say this:

```
messageEvent = if eventMethod == 'attachEvent' then 'onmessage' else 'message'
```

Or you could use a single conditional combined with an `if` expression and a [destructured assignment](http://coffeescript.org/#destructuring) to do it all at once:

```
[eventer, event] = if window.addEventListener
                       [window.addEventListener, 'message']
                   else
                       [window.attachEvent, 'onmessage' ]
eventer event, ...
```

This approach keeps everything together and, IMO, results in much clearer code.